# Gzip json data does not reduce the size of content in cordova android

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, json, cordova

I enabled Gzip compression for better performance of client and server in rails 4 by adding a line in application.rb as following

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Deflater
```

The json content is compressed from 915Kb to 184Kb with Content-Encoding:gzip
and Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8. It works well in web browser.

I run cordova application in android device 4.4.4, the size of content is 915kb as it is not compressed at all. The response header in Chrome Developer tool shows as the web one (Content-Encoding:gzip
and Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8) except the size of the content.

My question is why the compressed content data size is not smaller than uncompressed one?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested on android version 5.1, the file compression is smaller. It means it works well in android 5.1. I think, android version 4.4.4 does not support gzip.